# Is there a way to aref and setf several elements of an array?

Tags: common-lisp, scientific-computing

I am interested in numerical analysis and have recently began a love affair with Common LISP. I have found my thought processeses strongly influenced by years of more imperative style programming, so I am on a quest to develop a more lispy approach. A common theme for those on the LISP path, I presume.

Anyway, reading through CLTL2 it is stated that vectors can be accessed in constant time, whereas accessing a list is done in linear time (sec. 2.5.1). One can then `(setf (apply #'aref *some-vector* idx) new-value)` to set one place of a vector. My two-part question is:

a. Is there a way to get several values of an array by giving a list indices, without having to loop through the list? E.g., something akin to a correct version of `(map 'array #'aref *some-array* idx-list)`.

b. Is there a way to set the values of some elements of an array in the same spirit as above? It would be ideal to be able to apply a function (via an adequately defined `map`, or to `reduce` it, etc.) to a list of values extracted from arrays for, say, sampling and interpolation.

I would also appreciate any comments regarding array operations in general and numerical computing in particular (pointers to a tutorial or book, some mailing list, common pitfalls, when to use lists or other data structures instead, etc.).

Cheers.

Comment: The question is too broad. Stackoverflow is about Programming problems, not general advice. Your question best describes a specific real problem and comes with source code.

Comment: You should look into Paul Khuong's blog - he does numerical analyses with CL: http://www.pvk.ca/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.

You can map to get to get the values by index like this:

```
(map 'vector #'(lambda (idx) (aref *some-array* idx)) idx-list)
```

Note that this works only for one-dimensional arrays. A more-than-one-dimensional version would look like this:

```
(map 'vector #'(lambda (idx) (apply #'aref *some-array* idx)) idx-list)
```

Answer (score 3):

b. You *can* assign several *consecutive* values at once:

```lisp
(setf (subseq vector start end) values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid looping, since a function like `MAP` must loop anyway.

But you can use `MAP`, in combination with a function that creates a cyclic list, e.g.

```
(defun cycle (x)
   (let ((result (list x)))
      (setf (cdr result) result)
    result))

(defun multiple-aref (array indices)
   (map 'vector #'aref (cycle array) indices))

(multiple-aref '#(a b c d e f g) '(1 3 5))
```

=> `#(B D F)`

`(cycle array)` creates the infinite list `(array array array array ...)`. But `MAP` still works because it only examines an many elements as there are in the *shortest* list it is given (in this case `'(1 2 3)`).

Comment: Very interesting; your answer is enlightening in an oblique way. It would be nice if the values returned were `setf`-able, but would make for enough material for a different post.